# Regex to parse odata query

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to parse an odata query to replace `&$skip=0` with an empty value.

```
Objects?$filter=(Class eq 'Test')&$top=1000&$skip=0
```

Tried replacing using the below code but this does not remove `&$` from the query.

```
queryURL = queryURL.replace("/skip=\d+/", "");
```

Please suggest how I can achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Is skip always the last part of the query? and is it always preceded by the '&'?

Comment: No skip is not always the last part of query but it is always preceded by &$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```js
let queryURL = "Objects?$filter=(Class eq 'Test')&$top=1000&$skip=0";
queryURL = queryURL.replace(/&\$skip=\d+/, "");

console.log(queryURL)
```

Make sure you don't use quotes for the first argument, otherwise it will try to replace the literal string `"/&\$skip=\d+/"` and not use the regex expression